# PHP Performing a persistent DB check

Tags: php

I'm actually trying to create a ( more or less ) instant chat.
There's just one thing left to go, until it's finished. And that's a DB check for new entries every second by PHP itself.
A while loop works great for it, because i can exit it perfectly.
The Problem is, that the "every second" thing isn't working.
I tried a sleep(1), but that causes a 1 minute server freeze, until the script has been completed.
Hope someone can help me, i'm actually frustrated about this problem.

```
    elseif($latestID != 'undefined' && $_POST['returnafter'] == '60')
    {
      $timeout = '60';
      $i = '0';
      while ($i != $timeout)
      {
      $chat_content = "";
      $i++;
        $getLastID = mysql_query("SELECT id, userid, content, time_posted FROM (SELECT * FROM chat_system ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 150) chat_system WHERE id > '" . $latestID . "' $extraQuery ORDER BY id ASC");
        while ($lastID = mysql_fetch_object($getLastID))
        {
          $rowID = $lastID->id;
          $user_posted_id = $lastID->userid;
          $chat_content = $lastID->content;
          $chat_posted = $lastID->time_posted;
          $getUserData = mysql_query("SELECT username, avatar, loggedIn FROM account_data WHERE account_id=('" . $user_posted_id . "')");
          while ($userData = mysql_fetch_object($getUserData))
          {
            $username = $userData->username;
            $useravatar = $userData->avatar;
            $loginStatus = $userData->loggedIn;
          }

          if ($loginStatus == '1')
          {
            $onlineStatus = '<img src="./images/3DArt/newOnline.png" class="chat_onlineStatus">';
          }
          else
          {
            $onlineStatus = '<img src="./images/3DArt/newOffline.png" class="chat_onlineStatus">';
          }

          if (date('Y-m-d', $chat_posted) == date('Y-m-d'))
          {
            $time_posted = strftime('Heute, %H:%M', $chat_posted);
          }
          elseif (date('Y-m-d', $chat_posted) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Yesterday")))
          {
            $time_posted = strftime('Gestern, %H:%M', $chat_posted);
          }
          elseif (date('Y-m-d', $chat_posted) < date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Yesterday")))
          {
            $time_posted = strftime("%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M", $chat_posted);
          }

          if (isset($_POST['parseEmoticons']) && $_POST['parseEmoticons'] == 'true')
          {
            $chat_content = emoticons($chat_content);
          }

          $newChatRow.= '<div class="chatRow" id="' . $rowID . '">
  <div class="chatRow_container">
  <div><img src="' . $useravatar . '" class="chatAvatar">' . $onlineStatus . '<a href="/?page=Profile&amp;User=' . $user_posted_id . '"><b>' . $username . '</b></a>
    </div>
  </div>' . $modActions . '
    <div class="chat_mainMsg">
        ' . $chat_content . '
    </div>
    <div class="chatTime">' . $time_posted . '</div>
</div>';
        }

        $content = str_replace(array(
          '\r\n',
          '\r',
          '\n'
        ) , "<br />", $newChatRow);


        if(!empty($chat_content)) { echo $newChatRow; $i = $timeout; return false; }
        if(empty($chat_content)) { sleep(1); return true; }

      }
    }
```

I think, this informations should be enough. If not, just ask.

EDIT:  The request is initialized by Ajax and on success the request repeats.
       That's why PHP have to check for 60 seconds.

Comment: Why don't you try client side scripting for these checks?

Comment: Because that causes more traffic and is slower.

Comment: WebSockets are client side, they react on messages when server initiates the "talk". How is that more traffic or slower?

Comment: Sounded more like "Just send ajax requests".
I won't use Websockets because i already have built a big system and would have to change everything.
Or it is possible to use them just for one thing like this?

Comment: If it's a web application you will have hard time rendering information on each `while()` iteration. If you run it as CLI, as maybe you are aware of console application (the basic application learnt in languages like Java and C#), you will be much in ease using `while()` with sleep and breakpoints, but once your application reach the end it will terminate and you will not recieve/post any more messages in this chat, so you must be aware that in the whole lifecycle of this program, you should be in one big `while()` which I consider bad, so you either switch to sockets or get hard time codding

Comment: In computer systems that use code which respects *separation of concerns*, it should be trivial to use a protocol such as WebSockets instead of HTTP/AJAX for supplying the code with data. Technically, whether you use WS or HTTP/AJAX is irrelevant for the code that *works* with your data (in this case - chat app). However, seeing that you've used an ineffective method for obtaining the data (query every N seconds), I would strongly suggest, if and when you get the time - to consider proper architectural approach to solve your problem. As it is now, it's handled suboptimally and can cause issues

Comment: I already use the old verion of the system. A simple ajax request every X seconds. It's enough for a good chatting-flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should let the clientside decide what messages it "like" to receive.
eg you call your `messages.php` class - per ajax on the client side and pass a timestamp when the last time was the script requested new messages

example:

ajax interval with 1 second loop call the `messages.php?last=123456` and receive all messages that were created after or equal this timestamp. now you update in javascript the last timestamp and so on.

or you use a perfect framework (if possible) that is designed perfectly for your task to solve this.

http://socket.io/ (or js keyword `websockets`)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the solution i want to.
It's just all about the sleep-freeze.

Comment: what if i say your solution you want to is not designed for a problem like this?` i made a few chats in php some time ago and trust me this is the cleanest method i found when you try this without sockets

Comment: At the moment, ajax sends the last row-ID of the chat.
And PHP just searches for new entries, whose id is higher.

That's my solution so far.
I better stay here.

But thanks nevertheless.

Comment: glad that this may helped you